# r geom_bar reorder layers of bars by values

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have produced a bar chart that shows cumulative totals over periods of months for various programs using the following data structure and code:

```
library(dplyr)
data_totals <- data_long %>% 
  group_by(Period, Program) %>%
  arrange(Period, Program) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(Program) %>%
  mutate(Running_Total = cumsum(Value))



dput(data_totals)
structure(list(Period = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), .Label = c("2018-04", "2018-05", 
"2018-06", "2018-07", "2018-08", "2018-09", "2018-10", "2018-11", 
"2018-12", "2019-01", "2019-02", "2019-03", "Apr-Mar 2019"), class = "factor"), 
    Program = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("A", 
    "B", "C", "D", 
    "E"), class = "factor"), Value = c(5597, 
    0, 0, 0, 1544, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1544, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1544, 0, 0, 
    850, 0, 1544, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1544, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1544, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1544, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1544, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1544, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1544, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1544, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1544), Running_Total = c(5597, 
    0, 0, 0, 1544, 5597, 0, 0, 0, 3088, 5597, 0, 0, 0, 4632, 
    5597, 0, 850, 0, 6176, 5597, 0, 850, 0, 7720, 5597, 0, 850, 
    0, 9264, 5597, 0, 850, 0, 10808, 5597, 0, 850, 0, 12352, 
    5597, 0, 850, 0, 13896, 5597, 0, 850, 0, 15440, 5597, 0, 
    850, 0, 16984, 5597, 0, 850, 0, 18528)), .Names = c("Period", 
"Program", "Value", "Running_Total"), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -60L), vars = "Program", labels = structure(list(
    Program = structure(1:5, .Label = c("A", 
    "B", "C", "D", 
    "E"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), vars = "Program", drop = TRUE, .Names = "Program"), indices = list(
    c(0L, 5L, 10L, 15L, 20L, 25L, 30L, 35L, 40L, 45L, 50L, 55L
    ), c(1L, 6L, 11L, 16L, 21L, 26L, 31L, 36L, 41L, 46L, 51L, 
    56L), c(2L, 7L, 12L, 17L, 22L, 27L, 32L, 37L, 42L, 47L, 52L, 
    57L), c(3L, 8L, 13L, 18L, 23L, 28L, 33L, 38L, 43L, 48L, 53L, 
    58L), c(4L, 9L, 14L, 19L, 24L, 29L, 34L, 39L, 44L, 49L, 54L, 
    59L)), drop = TRUE, group_sizes = c(12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L
), biggest_group_size = 12L)

    # reorder the groups descending so that the lowest total will be on layers from front to back
reorder(data_totals$Program, -data_totals$Running_Total)

ggplot(data = data_totals, aes(x = Period, y = Running_Total)) +
  geom_bar(aes(color = Program, group = Program, fill = Program), 
           stat = "identity", position = "identity", alpha = 1.0)
```

It works in that it creates the graph with all the proper data, but the smaller Running_Totals are obscured by the larger ones.
I get the following error message as well:

```
Warning message:
The plyr::rename operation has created duplicates for the following name(s): (`colour`)
```

Even though I do not have the plyr package loaded.

I can see all the Running_Totals if I set the alpha to 0.5

Running_Total for each Program by Period, alpha = 0.5:

[image: img]

How can I get the layers ordered so that the smallest values are on the front most layers working back toward the highest values?

Comment: Few things: it would be helpful for you to post a workable sample of your data, like the output of `dput`, rather than the printout. The column `Source` doesn't exist in `data_totals`, at least as you've posted it. And you list `color` twice in your `aes`

Comment: Also, what's your desired result? You set `position = "identity"`, so the bars are placed exactly by their values without taking their groups into account. Do you actually intend to dodge them, stack them, etc?

Comment: thanks @camille.  I fixed the typos with an edit (Source should have been Program, and I deleted the duplicate color), and replaced the table with the output of dput.  As for desired result: I would like the values to stack to the highest value for each Period.  With position ="stack" the top value for each Period is the sum of all the groups together, position="fill" sets them all to 1.0.

Comment: @camille, as I think more about it, stacked is probably the more appropriate way to represent the data in this case. With labels using geom_text to show the values represented from each group.

Comment: About the warning: I get an error that you didn't post here ("Column `colour` must have a unique name"). The part about `plyr::rename` is a warning, not an error, and it's because of functions loaded by `ggplot2`. But all of that is only because you had `color` assigned twice, so if you've fixed that typo, this portion of your question is no longer relevant

Comment: thanks again @camille.  I have fixed all that and now have decided to change to a stacked bar to illustrate the data.  should I post the results of that once I have fixed it, or should I just delete this question as it is not really relevant, given that the way I was trying to represent the data does not make much sense after some thought?

Answer (score 0):

The way I was trying to represent the data in the original question was flawed.

There is no advantage to having the Program with the maximum value for each Period be the top of the bar.

A more illustrative solution is to have a stacked bar, with labels indicating the contribution of each Program to the overall value of each Period:

```
ggplot(data = data_totals[which(data_totals$Running_Total > 0),], aes(x = Period, y = Running_Total, fill = Program)) +
  geom_bar(aes(color = Program, group = Program, fill = Program), stat = "identity", position = "stack", alpha = 1.0) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Running_Total), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

[image: stacked bar chart with labels showing contribution of each Program to the total Value over the Periods]

I used `[which(data_totals$Running_Total > 0),]` to eliminate any "0" bars and labels.